# Comparison of two cell values always returns not equal

Tags: vba, excel

For whatever reason, the `If zoneChanged.Columns(-5).Value <> correctZone.Columns(2).Value Then` statement always evaluates as true, despite values in the cells being the same.  Perhaps at this point the values are never the same, but I cannot figure out why.  Also, the results that are returned alternate between two set of values even though that is not intended.  Here's the code in whole:

```
Sub panelSearch()

Dim Pos As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellFieldSet As Range
Dim cellSearchSet As Range
Dim cellBeingSearched As Range
Dim cellBeingSearchedFor As Range
Dim zoneChanged As Range
Dim correctZone As Range
Dim interVal As Range
'Area I am attempting to search
Set cellSearchSet = Range("U2:U8184") '8184
'Values I am searching for
Set cellFieldSet = Range("AI2:AI615")
i = 0

For Each cellBeingSearched In cellSearchSet

        For Each cellBeingSearchedFor In cellFieldSet

        Pos = InStr(cellBeingSearched, cellBeingSearchedFor.Value)

             If Pos > 0 Then 'code if found
             Set zoneChanged = cellBeingSearched
             Set correctZone = cellBeingSearchedFor
                    '-4142 is default color index

                 If zoneChanged.Columns(-5).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
                 'This control statement always evaluates as true even when the two cells should be the same
                    If zoneChanged.Columns(-5).Value <> correctZone.Columns(2).Value Then
                    'Need to add counter to keep multiple results from changing cell multiple times

                    zoneChanged.Columns(-5).ClearContents
                    zoneChanged.Columns(-5) = zoneChanged.Columns(-5) & correctZone.Columns(2)

                    zoneChanged.Columns(-5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                        'Counter for multiple results
                        If i > 0 Then
                        zoneChanged.Columns(-5).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                        End If


                    End If
                      i = i + 1
                 End If

            End If
        Next cellBeingSearchedFor

    Next cellBeingSearched
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this `.Columns(-5)` won't work. This should already throw an error. To go  5 cells left use `.Offset(0, -5)` instead. Same for `.Columns(2)` should be  `.Offset(0, 2)` accordingly.

Comment: I wonder why `.Columns(-5)` doesn't throw an Error 1004 for you. for me it does. You just cannot use negative values in `.Columns`. Therefor `Offset` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: That worked!  I cannot mark it as answer with the comment nested under mine though.  When I see what cell is being selected by columns(-5) using the .select method it actually highlights the correct cells.  None the less, it doesn't operate predictably.  The offset method works though.

Comment: this is strange. Nevertheless, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that @DisplayName pointed out that my explanation was not correct, I got a bit deeper into it. Nevertheless the solution does not change, just my explanation why.

So the issue in the question was obviously, that it just shifted the wrong amount of columns because of (at first glance) **a very odd counting system of the `column` property** (which is not that odd if we looked into it).

#### Counting of Columns

When dealing with row/column counts, Excel starts counting at `1`. So if we do `Column(1).Select` it selects the first column which is `A`. So the parameter we give at the `column` property is the **column number** (and not the amount we want to shift).

So because `Column(1)` is the first column (eg. of a selected range) that means that `Column(0)` is one left of the first column (of the selected range).

So if we use `column` for shifting `.Columns(-1)` shifts the selection `2` columns to the left, and yes I mean TWO.

```
Columns(5).Columns(-1).Select 
Debug.Print Selection.Column '= 3
```

If we think in shifting we would await that this selects column 4 (go one left). But it selects the **column number** `-1` where the current column is column number 1. So counting from `1` (current) to `-1` (destination) it is `2` steps left of `1` and that's why it shifts `2` left.

**Conclusion**
I conclude that `Columns()` should be used to jump to a specific column number. But when we want to shift (a specific amount of columns) relatively to the current selection we should use `Offset()` for a convenient counting.

#### Counting of Offset

So `Offset` is shifting as expected where `.Offset(0, -1)` shifts selection `1` column to the left (as `-1` let us expect).

To go 5 cells left use `.Offset(0, -5)` instead. Same for `.Columns(2)` should be `.Offset(0, 2)` accordingly.

```
Columns(5).Offset(0, -1).Select
Debug.Print Selection.Column '= 4
```

For more information look into the documentation: [Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)

Comment: actually `.Columns(-5)` works for me... Of course it must not reference a cell left of column "A", but that applies to`.Offset()` too..

Comment: @DisplayName `Dim r As Range: Set r = range("D10"):  r.Columns(-3).Select` doesn't work but `Dim r As range: Set r = Columns(5):  r.Columns(-3).Select` does. So the point here is that he startet on a range that was no full column and therefore he needs to use offset. I added the explanation why it didn't work.

Comment: well, `range("V10").Columns(-5).select` works (at least from Immediate Window)

Comment: @DisplayName well you are completely right it works, **but now it gets even more odd:** `Dim r As range: Set r = range("D10"): r.Columns(-1).Select` selects range **B10** where I would expect C10 to be selected. Now it is obvious why going `.Columns(-3)` from  `D10` ended up in an error. But the counting is really mysterious why a `-1` means going 2 cells left. I can only recommend to avoid using that.

Comment: Seems like negative values would shift you one more column to the left then _equivalent_ `.Offset()` would. Should that be all, I'd consider it for less verbosity than `Offset()`, but with special care...

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks, again for pointing the issue out. I changed the explanation accordingly to the 2 different counting systems of `Column` and `Offset`. Nevertheless it doesn't change the solution.

Comment: @Peh, fine job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because you're using a negative value  (-5) as index for columns.

As far as I know you should use a positive number as index.

Comment: Just for your interest: Obviously the negative value is not the issue here as we found out (which surprised me too).